# parameters between uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController opened when a button is pressed in the previous one:

In the first one:

```
-(IBAction)info:(id)sender{

MapInfo *infoView = [[MapInfo alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];
}
```

I would like to send two parameters to MapInfo, but I cant find how to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question comes up again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either write custom init method and use that instead of `initWithNibName:bundle:`

```
- (id) initWithParameter1:(id)parameter1 parameter2:(id) parameter2:(id)parameter
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle: nil]){
        // custom initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

or you can add properties for your parameters in `MapInfo` and set them before presenting:

```
MapInfo *infoView = [[MapInfo alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
infoView.parameter1 = parameter1;
infoView.parameter2 = parameter2;
[self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];
```

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to create custom init methods. It leads to verbose code, incompatibility with Xcode tools and unpredictable bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about application architecture design (design patterns, oop, etc).

I would have done that like so:
You have the Model object, and two controllers, every controllers have access to Model instance. Then one controller change data in the model and present another controller. Thus another one controller have access too to the new data.

Resource for reading:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Objective-C-Design-Patterns-iOS/dp/1430233303/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1345636110&sr=8-5&keywords=cocoa+design+pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233303)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

create a custom method in MapInfo with the parameters

```
 //assuming you want NSString for parameter type
-(id)initWithParameterOne:(NSString*)one parameterTwo:(NSString*)two
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
       .......
    }

    return self;
}
```

do not forget to add `-(id)initWithParameterOne:(NSString*)one parameterTwo:(NSString*)two;` in you MapInfo header

you can call it then like

```
-(IBAction)info:(id)sender{

MapInfo *infoView = [[MapInfo alloc] initWithParameterOne:dataOne parameterTwo:dataTwo];
[self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];
}
```